# Need reference of shloka from video?

Tags: mahabharata, shloka, reference-request

[In this video pravachana guru is tell sloka I want this sloka and reference](https://youtu.be/kyQDqX26W6g)

Please seek 10:38 mins

Comment: I have given mins in below

Comment: Now I have given